# ExpectUpdate for a submit button

Tags: r, shiny

I am checking my shiny app if it is running properly or not. So one method is using expectUpdate.

```
app <- ShinyDriver$new(getwd())
expectUpdate(app, n = 5, add = 1, output = "sum", timeout = 3000)
Error: Updating ‘n’, ‘add’ did not update ‘sum’, or it is taking longer than 3000 ms.
```

App below

```
shinyApp(
    fluidPage(
        numericInput("n", "Number to add", 5),
        actionButton("add", "Add"),
        verbatimTextOutput("sum", placeholder = TRUE)
    ),
    function(input, output, session) {
        nums <- numeric()

        c_sum <- eventReactive(input$add, {
            nums <<- c(nums, input$n)
            sum(nums)
        })

        output$sum <- renderText({
            c_sum()
        })




    }
)
```

Comment: Please show your app and explain what you mean by "not working".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually it is confidential. :) But below error I am getting ````Error: Updating ‘ID’, ‘Date’, ‘Submit’ did not update ‘table’, or it is taking longer than 3000 ms.````

Comment: But the app is working very fine when I click Submit button

Comment: I'd say it's working fine for me, but ... without your code (and only recently hearing about some error), there's a bit more you need to include in your question. If you can spend some time to derive a similar ultra-simple shiny app that behaves the same (and is not confidential), then we'll be able to help. (I'm not poo-poo-ing the confidential part, that's often a difficult thing to work around.)

Comment: Indeed, that does not seem to work.

Comment: Yeah. But I’m thinking what could be the reason. There is another I saw in google and it’s working wel for that. If u need I can share the link

Comment: @imranp Yes, please share the link.

Comment: The dataset is in https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/050-kmeans-example. You can see the operation in https://rstudio.github.io/shinytest/reference/expectUpdate.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like updating a button does not work with `expectUpdate`. Here is another way which performs the same test:

```
library(shinytest)
library(testthat)

app <- ShinyDriver$new(getwd())
old_sum <- app$getValue("sum")
app$setInputs(add = "click")
new_sum <- app$getValue("sum")
expect_false(old_sum == new_sum)
app$stop()
```

Comment: Hi Stephane. I just observed few things here. After I run ````app <- ShinyDriver$new(getwd()) ```` I get this error ````> app <- ShinyDriver$new(getwd())
Error in supervisor_start() : 
  processx supervisor was not ready after 5 seconds.
Type .Last.error.trace to see where the error occured````

Comment: Hi @stephane. After I perform ````old_sum <- app$getValue("sum")````. I get this error ````Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to connect to xxx.x.x.x port xxxx: Connection refused````

Comment: Hi @stephane. Small query but quite important. Can you please help me here. I can run ````app <- ShinyDriver$new(getwd())```` in my local system. But when I deploy to Rstudio connect server, I am not able to . Is there any specific reason for this? Wanted to check also if there is any alternate for this?